# What's the function of $imageId parameter in Image Helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image)

Tags: magento2, product-images, image

What's the **function** of **$imageId** parameter in Magento2 Image Helper?

What is the **value** I should assign to it if I create a new module for new purpose?

```
$_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$_imagehelper->init($_product, $imageId)->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize('400', '400');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In magento theme you might see a file  `view.xml`

> ...\app\design\frontend[VENDOR][THEME]\etc\view.xml

```
<media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            ...
            <image id="CUSTOM_IMAGE_ID" type="[IMAGE_TYPE]">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            ...
        </images>
</media>
```

**IMAGE_TYPE = small_image | thumbnail | image**

**CUSTOM_IMAGE_ID =  Is a unique id**, which we can assign to respective area or in a module.

**Example : minicart image magento give name mini_cart_product_thumbnail**

So now come to the your question **$imageId   = CUSTOM_IMAGE_ID**

So in magento 2, **not need to hard code image size in code** that can be manageable in theme level, just go to respective theme and respective `etc/view.xml`

and update size (width/height/ ...) for respective image id

**Image Type** will help to get respective image from magento

like base image you need to resize then use `type = image`